# Keycloak JavaScript adapter to generate token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to implement a keycloak javaScript adapter to deal with the scenario of token expiration in my code. Although my token expires every 5 minutes, my objective is that by using the adapter, keycloak will continue to renovate the token as needed without me having to implement that logic.

Here's my code (it basically allows me to write in the browser and save the text that is written by clicking "Save":

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { MyEditor } from '@editor/my-editor';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'; // Import the Keycloak library

function MyEditor() {
  const apiURL = 'http://localhost:1777/editor/api/v1/note';

  const [keycloak, setKeycloak] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isSaving, setIsSaving] = useState(false);
  const [editorText, setEditorText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    initKeycloak();
  }, []);

  const initKeycloak = async () => {
    const keycloakInstance = new Keycloak({
      url: 'http://keycloak:1900/auth/realms/myeditor/protocol/openid-connect/token', //Keycloak server URL
      realm: 'myeditor',
      grant_type: 'credential', 
      clientId: 'client',
      clientSecret: 'secret'
    });

    try {
      await keycloakInstance.init({ onLoad: 'check-sso' });
      setKeycloak(keycloakInstance);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error initializing Keycloak:', error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const generateRandomId = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  };

  const makeApiRequest = async () => {
    if (!keycloak.token) {
      console.log('No token available.'); 
      return;
    }

    const postData = {
      data: {
        correlationId: generateRandomId(),
        subjectId: generateRandomId().toString(),
        text: editorText,
      },
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch(apiURL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + keycloak.token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(postData),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        // Handle API response
      } else {
        console.error('API request failed:', response.status, response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error making API request:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleSaveButtonClick = async () => {
    setIsSaving(true);

    try {
      await makeApiRequest();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    } finally {
      setIsSaving(false);
    }
  };

  const handleEditorChange = (newText) => {
    setEditorText(newText);
  };

  return (
    <div className="editor-container">
      {isLoading ? (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      ) : keycloak ? (
        <React.Fragment>
          <MyEditor
            tokenProvider={{ getToken: () => keycloak.token }}
            defaultValue={editorText}
            onChange={handleEditorChange}
          />
          <button onClick={handleSaveButtonClick} disabled={isSaving}>
            {isSaving ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'}
          </button>
        </React.Fragment>
      ) : (
        <p>Error initializing Keycloak.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyEditor;
```

I know that the parameters are correct because if I use postman it generates the token as expected (image below). But when I try to run my application I get this error in the console:

error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

[error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaY7M.png)

postman request that works fine:

[postman request working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPx3X.png)

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#using-the-adapter) url attribute should be `base url + path` of you keycloak instance.

Change your url from 'http://keycloak:1900/auth/realms/myeditor/protocol/openid-connect/token' to 'http://keycloak:1900/auth'

Comment: Thanks! Changed the url and now I get a 400 error. Is there any specific syntax adaptation that needs to be done in order that keycloak doesn't fail to accept the parameters sent? I've checked the documentation as it is the first time I'm using keycloak but didn't found much related to that. The problem seems to be that, although the parameters are correct (I use the same ones in the Postman request).

Comment: Keycloak log should point something which helps.. Have you checked that?